# renderPlotly() in shiny creating jpeg in server dir

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shiny-server

I'm trying to deploy an app on Ubuntu Shiny-sever. I'm finding that when I attempt to run the app that it fails when it tries to access a graph generated by `renderPlotly()` because the shiny-sever only has read access to the app folder. When I `sudo chmod -R 777 /folder` the app works and populates a `*.jpeg` called `Rplot001.jpeg` in the app folder.

While this works, my preference would be to change the output directory of these files to some directory other than the root app directory. Does anyone know of/can point me to the setting to redirect these files?

Comment: you could create a folder and give shiny access: sudo chown shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server/YourApp/YourFolder

Comment: The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get `renderPlotly()` to generate this temporary `jpeg` anywhere else other than the `server.r` folder and thus can't move the reference to a more palatable location.

Comment: as work around, maybe you could use observeEvent, action button, and webshot to save your image